# How to add Git LFS in github actions to push larger files

Tags: github, github-actions, build.gradle, git-lfs, gitlab-ci.yml

I have created an action file in github which automates the pushing of framework located in build files to new branch. However now i am getting error while pushing as the build files are larger than 100MB. So i wanted to know how to incorporate Git Lfs or is there any other solutions.

```
name: Create Build Branch

jobs:
    CI:
       runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
       - name: Git-checkout
         uses: actions/checkout@v3

       - name: Build
         run: ./gradlew build

       - name: Generate Framework
         run: ./gradlew podPublishFramework

       - name: Push build to new branch
         uses: s0/git-publish-subdir-action@devlop
         env:
            REPO: self
            BRANCH: BuildFiles
            FOLDER: project/build/framework
            GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            TAG: 0.0.1
            MESSAGE: "Build: Pushed build files
```

I am getting error in step Push the framework to new branch as the framework size are larger than 100MB. Any approach to resolve this using actions would be helpful

Comment: You are using git and github in a totally not intended way. Don't push build artifacts to version control, use [artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) or [packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/managing-github-packages-using-github-actions-workflows/publishing-and-installing-a-package-with-github-actions).

Comment: I will be generating a jar file which will be in build folder and i have to release the jar file which is more than 100 MB, hence i need git lfs to push it to github